# Род зависимых слов

Tags: согласование

Как определяется род зависимых слов?  Например, что из следующего правильно:

- Чёрный шлем-маска лежал на столе.
- Чёрная шлем-маска лежала на столе.
- Чёрный шлем-маска лежала на столе.

или

```
  Бразилия и Индия выходят из БРИКС, верный друг Венесуэла тоже (подкачал? подкачала?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно: черный шлем-маска,  верный друг Венесуэла подкачала.

Пояснение

1) Кажется, что в русском правописании правил очень много, просто слова не напишешь без орфографического справочника. В действительности, правил немного, и большинство из них основано на грамматике.

В данном случае действует одно грамматическое  и поэтому вполне понятное правило: **согласование делается по главному слову в сочетании (определяемому существительному), а не по приложению.**

2) А как определить, где приложение? При дефисном написании приложение находится на втором месте, при раздельном - на первом.  А как же жар-птица? Если первая часть слова не склоняется, то это уже не словосочетание с приложением, а сложное слово, и его род определяется по второй (опорной) части.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: Чёрный шлем-маска лежал на столе ( склоняются обе части).
Здесь действует следующее правило: 
Род сложных имён существительных, пишущихся через  дефис, обычно определяется:

1)  по первой части, если изменяются обе части: моё кресло-кровать — моего кресла-кровати (ср.р.), новый самолёт-амфибия — нового самолёта-амфибии (м.р.);

2)  по второй части, если первая не изменяется: сверкающая жар-птица — сверкающую жар-птицу (ж.р.), огромная меч-рыба — огромной меч-рыбы (ж.р.).

В некоторых случаях род не определяется, так как сложное слово употребляется только во множественном числе: сказочные сапоги-скороходы — сказочных сапог-скороходов (мн.ч.)-

Правильно: ...верный друг Венесуэла тоже подкачала ( падкачала Венесуела -ж.р., а не друг). Поэтому согласование по по женск. роду.